# Collecting relative altitude from barometer in iPhone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, core-motion, iphone-6

I am trying to use the barometer sensor in the new iPhones to display vertical speed on the devices. I have ended up with the following code in my "motion" model, which does executes to give more or less appropriate values.

I am however experiencing problems in terms of updating my View as `startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue` is executed. The value of `userRelativeAltitude` is updated, but the function never returns anything(presumably because it is executing the `startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesTo Queue` works like a loop.?). I am afraid the whole statement has ended rather above my head..

I set out to have functionality more like that of e.g. `startAccelerometerUpdates`. Is there any better way of collecting data from the barometer?

Also, how do you check if the device has a barometer sensor available?

```
    - (float) pullRelativeAltitude {

self._altitudeManager = [[CMAltimeter alloc] init];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[self._altitudeManager startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

        _userRelativeAltitude = altitudeData.relativeAltitude.floatValue;
        NSLog(@"%f", altitudeData.relativeAltitude.floatValue);

    });
}];

NSLog(@"This is relative altitude: %f", _userRelativeAltitude is );

return _userRelativeAltitude;
```

}

Suggestions would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, the following code will check to see if altitude is available:

```
if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
  // your code
}
```

I can't get any barometer readings either, however.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured it out, but this worked for me.
One thing to add, and you probably already figured this out, you cannot be in the simulator. You need an iPhone 6 or 6+ and the app has to be running on the phone :)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    BOOL isReady = [CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable];
    if( isReady ) {
        NSLog(@"yes");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no");
    }
    alt = [[CMAltimeter alloc] init];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [alt startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            NSLog(@"%f", altitudeData.relativeAltitude.floatValue);

        });
    }];
}
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of [alt startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error) in swift?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, but I had to implement the code in the View Controller (and not the model) to update the UI with new reading. For others interested, my final coded ended up looking like this:

```
if ([CMAltimeter isRelativeAltitudeAvailable]) {
    self._altitudeManager = [[CMAltimeter alloc] init];

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    [self._altitudeManager startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:queue withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {

            //provide relative altitude
            float relativeAltitude;
            relativeAltitude = altitudeData.relativeAltitude.floatValue;
            self.userRelativeAltitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f m", relativeAltitude];

        });
    }];

} else {
    NSLog(@"barometer not available");
    _userVario.text = @"no barometer available";
}
```

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Note that if you immediately dispatch to the main queue from the callback, you can just as well simply use the main queue directly. Use "queue = [NSOperationQueue mainQueue];".